# Kerberos authentication for web request in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos

I'm trying to implement exactly this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part6.html

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

public class RunHttpSpnego {

    static final String kuser = "username"; // your account name
    static final String kpass = "password"; // your password for the account

    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
            // and Negotiate, the usrname and password are all the same.
            System.err.println("Feeding username and password for "
               + getRequestingScheme());
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
        URL url = new URL(args[0]);
        InputStream ins = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        String str;
        while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

I've already reduced to trying just to execute the sample code snippet, but I don't know how to overcome this issue I'm facing.
As I understand, the flow for such requests should look like, as detailed in this document as well:
1. The clients sends a HTTP GET request to the server
2. The server responds with a HTTP 401, and a WWW Authenticate: Negotiate header
3. Then the client sends another HTTP GET request, this time with the proper Negotiate header in the request.

My problem is, when I try to run that sample, the request fails with an IOException obviously, because of the server responding with a 401, and then I don't know how to issue the second request with the header. I was trying to add a header as with Basic Authentication, but in that case I don't know where to get the Negotiate value for that from.
I did a packet capture, I can see the TGS ticket being requested from the KDC, so I think that part is OK, I just don't know how it should be applied to my request. I did the same packet capture with other scripts connecting to the same web service, and I can see the exact same flow what I've described above.

So, to summarize my question: how should I add the authentication header to my request? Do I need to do it explicitely in my code, if so, how do I do it?